# How do I redirect a URL with htaccess passing only the parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to accomplish the following with htaccess redirect.

How do I replace/redirect this

/kb_results.asp?ID=16

by

/catalogsearch/result/?q=16

So the url in the end is domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=16

Thanks in advance for any tips or help.

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite, you can add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^kb_results.asp$ /catalogsearch/result/?q=%1 [L,R]
```

If you want the redirect to be permanent, change the `R` flag to `R=301`, or if you want the URI to be internally rewritten (instead of an external redirect), then remove the `R` flag entirely.